# "x.exe has stopped workinng" al leer un string usando scanf_s en visual studio 2015?

Tags: c

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes con el siguiente codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
 char c[10];
 printf("nombre\n");
 scanf("%s",&c);
 printf("%s",c);
}
```

El problema es que al introducir el nombre y presionar  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> "x.exe has stopped working".

He probado colocando mas librerias e intercambiando `char c[10]` por `char *c`

El mismo código lo eh probado en borland(compilador de c y c++) y allí no me da ningún problema, asi que el problema debe de estar en visual studio.

Comment: solucionado, por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, cuando se usa string_s en visual studio, tiene que ir algo asi, en mi caso es: string_s(%s,c,sizeof(c));

Answer (score 2):

1. Con los arrays, el nombre de la variable ya funciona como dirección a la zona de memoria definida por el array, no es necesario obtener la dirección mediante el operador `&`.

   ```
    scanf("%s", c);
   ```
2. Como defines un array de 10 caracteres, el nombre que introduzcas puede tener como máximo 9 caracteres (el último siempre se usa para un caracter `null` - `\0` que marca el fin del string). No pones que valor usas para la prueba así que tenlo en cuenta.
3. > El mismo código lo eh probado en borland(compilador de c y c++) y allí no me da ningún problema, asi que el problema debe de estar en visual studio.

   C y C++ son famosos porque no hacen comprobaciones si el programa está mal escrito; se crearon pensando sobre todo en la velocidad de ejecución. ¿Que tu programa llama a una dirección de memoria sin inicializar? Es tu problema. No está definido que el programa te avise del error; de hecho no hay definido como debe comportarse el programa. En algunos casos puede *parecer que funciona*, en otros casos el programa puede parar su ejecución, en otros continuará la ejecución con comportamientos inesperados. Es lo que se llama "comportamiento indefinido" (*undefined behavior*, UB), y puede hacer depurar programas en C/C++ complicado.

Comment: "*C y C++ son famosos porque no hacen comprobaciones si el programa está mal escrito*" Esto es completamente falso: si un programa está mal escrito no compila. El no hacer verificaciones sobre datos se hace por eficiencia (sigue la premisa de "don't pay for what you don't use") no por desidia. C++ genera código más seguro que C al ofrecer comprobaciones eficientes en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster un programa que usa UB (por ejemplo, escribiendo en una memoria que no tiene asignada o haciendo buffer overflows) está mal escrito, aunque compile. Y en ningún punto he hablado de "desidia"; de hecho he especificado que el objetivo primordial de C/C++ es la velocidad.

Comment: El uso de comportamiento indefinido no es indicativo de que el programa esté mal escrito si no de que se usan mal las herramientas ofrecidas por el lenguaje al violar pre/postcondiciones de funciones perfectamente documentadas... pero llegados a este punto, si seguimos la conversación entraremos en un debate semántico en lugar de técnico.

Comment: Si alguien usa un cuchillo para matar a alguien es porque el cuchillo está mal diseñado o porque alguien hace un uso incorrecto del mismo?? pues lo mismo es aplicable a C, C++ y un gran abanico de lenguajes